# divs not floating side by side

Tags: html, css

I need help troubleshooting my floating divs  which are not aligning side by side as they are currently below each other. are contained inside of another div  which floats properly.
JSFIDDLE LINK:https://jsfiddle.net/bgu5orh7/5/

This is my HTML summarized:

```
<body> 
    <div id="left"> ... </div>
    <div id="right"> 
    <div class="thumb"> ... </div>
    <div class="thumb"> ... </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my css: 
(found on line 221 of the jsfiddle css)

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
#left{
    width:25%;
    padding:3% 5% 0% 5%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}

#right{
    width:65%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:30px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.thumb{
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    padding:20px 2.5px 0px 0px;
    display:block;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the relevant HTML in the question as well, and preferably make a snippet or a JSFiddle as well.

Comment: Probably a `box-sizing:border-box` issue.

Comment: We cannot help you without the entire relevant code as Roope said

Comment: Fiddle does not match the posted code.

Comment: Added the entire code in a jsfiddle link. The css section I included in the post can be found on like 221. Hope I'm doing this right. Thank you!

Comment: It seems to me that if you resize your page to make it wider, then the `<div>` tags will float properly on your page. If you want it to work on smaller displays, you should look into using Twitter Bootstrap or a similar grid system.

Comment: I am having trouble with <div class="thumb"> in particular. My intention is to have the small thumbnails display side by side when viewed on pages wider than 1000px. The rest of divs float properly.

Comment: the top level .thumb class appears to have a `clear: both;` in your `@media screen and (min-width: 1000px)` from fiddle would it help to add `clear: none`?

Comment: You should use `display: inline-block;`, not only with your thumb divs, but the containers as well... they will be side by side while there is enough width available, breaking down the right most one when there isn't enough width...

Comment: Yes Dave, that's it! Thank you all for comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Just simply change `display:block;` to `display:inline-block;` and everything should work fine.

```css
#left{
    width:25%;
    padding:3% 5% 0% 5%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

#right{
    width:65%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    padding:30px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.thumb{
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    padding:20px 2.5px 0px 0px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body> 
    <div id="left"> ... </div>
    <div id="right">
    <div class="thumb"> ... </div>
    <div class="thumb"> ... </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to accomplish can easily be achieved by changing the css `display`-attribute to `table-cell`.

The following code works:

```
/* 4. large desktop view */
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

#left{
    width:25%;
    padding:3% 5% 0% 5%;
    display:table-cell;
    float:left;
}

#right{
    width:65%;
    display:table-cell;
    float:left;
    padding:30px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.thumb{
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    padding-top:20px;
    display:block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mobile view code `clear:both` was carried into wide screen code interfering with the float.

```
.thumb{
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  padding-top:20px;
  clear:both;
}
```

fixed:

```
.thumb{
   width:100%;
   display:block;
   position:relative;
   float:left;
   padding-top:20px;
```

}